# How can I get the value of selected optgroup with jquery and select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use select2 for selectbox and made `<optgroup>` selectable, but I can't get the value when I select it.
It's very important to get all options of the `<optgroup>` when you type optgroup name, as a result I can't replace `<optgroup>` with ususal `<option>`.

---

See jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/iptspl/41r158dm/1/

Comment: What do you need the value to be formatted like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `choice` value on the event (if it exists) then check that for `children` and then combine their values.

```
on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
   var value, choice = e.choice; 
   if(choice.children && choice.children.length > 0) {
        value = [];
        $(choice.children).each(function(index, child) {
            value.push($(child.element).val());
        });
        value = value.join(",");
   } else {
        value = e.val;
   } 
   alert(value);
});
```

At any rate, whatever you do you will most likely need to do something similar which is detect if it is an `optgroup` and then traverse the children and create the value.